# Perl RegEx to get substring of word found between two tags

Tags: regex, perl

I have a question related to regex. I have an element as `$str1 = <strong>average_speed_answer_good_high</strong>`
What I am trying to do is to get the string before `"_good_high"` (which in this case is `"average_speed_answer"`) in a variable `$sub_str1` in one variable and `"good_high"` in a variable `$sub_str2`.

Here `"_good_high"` is the only constant part of the string and the rest can change. Even after `"_good_high"`, there could be some characters before `"</strong>"`. Can I get some tips on how I can do this?

Until now, I was able to do something like:

```
if ( $str1 =~ m{(<strong>)(.*?)(</strong>)} ) {
    $sub_str1 = $2; #which gives average_speed_answer_good_high
}
```

I have tried some combinations like,

```
(<strong>)(?=_good_high)(</strong>) 
(<strong>)(?<=_good_high)(</strong>) 
(<strong>)((?<=_good_high)\w+)(</strong>) #tried $2 and $3
(<strong>)(?<=_good_high)\w+(</strong>) 
(<strong>)((?<=(_good_high))\w+)(</strong>)#tried $2, $3 and $4
```

but they all put blank in `$sub_str1`.

I would appreciate any help or tips.

Comment: You seem somewhat lost in grouping, capturing, pattern matching, I tried to clarify this a bit with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32778391/2932052).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `_good_high` before the closing strong tag.

```
if ( $str1 =~ m{(<strong>)(.*?)_good_high.*?(</strong>)} ) {
    $sub_str1 = $2; 
}
```

or

```
if ( $str1 =~ m{<strong>(.*?)_good_high.*?</strong>} ) {
    $sub_str1 = $1; 
}
```

Comment: It appears that there is a missing `.*?` after `_good_high`, since the OP mentions that: Even after "_good_high" there could be some characters.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
($sub_str1) = $str1 =~ m{<strong>(.*?)_good_high</strong>};
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't get too hung up on regexes and capture groups. They're not the only tool in your box.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str1 = '<strong>average_speed_answer_good_high</strong>';
if ( my ($sub_str1) = $str1 =~ m{<strong>(.*?)</strong>} ) {
    print "Substr: $sub_str1\n";
    my @split_str = split ( /_/, $sub_str1 );
    print Dumper \@split_str; 
    print "Extracted: ",join ( "_", (split ( /_/, $sub_str1 ))[0..2] ),"\n";
}
```

We extract the substring as before - but then we split it using `_`:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'average',
          'speed',
          'answer',
          'good',
          'high'
        ];
```

And then stick it together again, preserving elements `0` to `2` to get your answer.

Comment: True, but by matching with a significant feature, you reduce dealing with uninteresting parts of the HTML.

Comment: Yes. Depends on the nature of the problem. But I might suggest moving away from regex to HTML parsers for anything more complex anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems seem to result from your understanding of the functioning of `(`, `)`, `?`, `.*`, and `.*`.

In your second-part examples, there is no variable part, only grouping, sometimes without capturing.

- `pre(.*)post` causes **capturing** up all between `pre` and `post` in `$1`
- `pre(?:a|b|c)post` causes **grouping** of alternatives without capturing
- `a(.*?)b` causes **non-greedy matching** (+capturing): matching **`x`** instead **`xby`** in `axbyb`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is as follows. Just look for all text except angle brackets that is preceded by a `<strong>` tag (there's no need to search for the end tag) followed by `_good_high`. That is the wanted substring

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = <<END;
<html>
  <body>
    <strong>average_speed_answer_good_high</strong>
  </body>
</html>
END

if ( my ($text) = $s =~ /<strong>([^<>]+)_good_high/ ) {
    print $text, "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
average_speed_answer
```

Comment: Thank you all for the inputs. I accepted Avinash Raj's answer as it resolves my problem and needed minimum changes. But other answers were also working for me. As Wolf mentioned it was problem in my understanding of regex which I'll work on. If anyone has any suggestions for online sources where I can practice regexes then that'll also be very helpful.

Comment: @300 Good to read that it helped :-) But you should understand, that all replies in comments are assigned to a question or answer, **not to the "page" as a whole**. This (as many other "pages") is only a collection of answers (5 so far) given to a specific question. So it may be reordered if users vote or add new answers.